# Parse.com confirmation email change

Tags: parse-platform

My app uses a parse.com backend. I'm having problems changing the confirmation sent from parse when users sign up. they get an email that asks them to confirm their email address but instead of it being from parse I want to change it to an email that has my own branding on it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey Rob, I saw you unaccepted my answer, is everything OK?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do it on the dashboard. Go to [parse.com](http://www.parse.com), select your app, then settings, then email. There you'll find the templates.

[image: Parse dashboard UI]